# What is the correct way to deal with migrations of Django Database when pushing files to the remote git repository?

Tags: django, git, github, migration, repository

Actually we are group of 3 people working on the same project, and each one individually make changes in django database. After running migrations in individual machine, it creates migration file for each migration. When someone pushes updated code in remote git repository, it creates conflict with others' migrations of same name.
Because of this reason, I lost my whole data once. Kindly give suggestions what should I do with this migration thing?

Answer (score 0):

here's what i do: whenever I want to fetch from remote i check if a duplicate migration will be fetched. (we have a script that checks for all migration directories if there are filenames which have the same starting number.) if that is the case, I 'merge' the migrations, usually like this:

1. Find the last migration *before the duplicate*, let's say it's migration 000X
2. Make sure you are on your local source version, before the duplicate is added.
3. migrate back to after migration n:

   ```
   python manage migrate app 000X
   ```
4. pull the new version including the duplicates.
5. remove your duplicate migrations
6. run schemamigration

   ```
   python manage schemamigration --auto
   ```

Now you should get a new migration adding your model changes on top of the changes that were made in the migration you pulled.